# Solving Apache "search permissions are missing on a component of the path" issue

Tags: apache-2.4, permissions

I'm learning as I go, so patience for my n00b tech skills is appreciated in advance.

I have a fresh Ubuntu 18 VPS. Fresh Apache (no apache2.conf changes). Fresh vsftpd. I added a user, added it to www-data usergroup, and chmod 775 /var/www/. Success, I can read/write that folder via FTP. But I've pooched Apache somehow.

Going to the root of my IP or domain on a browser returns an "Index of /" page with an empty table. Going to a file returns "403 Forbidden". Looking at the apache error log tells me "search permissions are missing on a component of the path", but I'm unable to find out how to troubleshoot that.

The only clue I have to work with is the following:

```
namei --modes /var/www/html
f: /var/www/html
drwxr-xr-x /
drwxr-xr-x var
drwxrwsr-x www
drwxr-xr-x html
```

Thank you

Comment: "namei" doesn't go deeper then what you specify. Try "namei -m /var/www/html/index.html"

Comment: Isn't it nice that Apache doesn't tell you /which/ component of the path. Increased the LogLevel?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I should have been more precise in my language.
> # namei --modes /var/www/html/2020
> f: /var/www/html/2020
> drwxr-xr-x /
> drwxr-xr-x var
> drwxrwsr-x www
> drwxr-xr-x html
>            2020 - No such file or directory

Comment: Who cares that 2020 doesn't exist? It's index.html that you need.

Comment: "No such file or directory" @GerardH.Pille

Comment: Put an index.html in /var/www/html and visit your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "find /var/www/html -type d -ls". One of the subdirs hasn't got the necessary x's.

Comment: Thank you. Each directory I want the public to access should be drwxrwxr-x/775, right? After setting the whole tree manually and restarting apache I still got no love. From my experience I shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: "setting the whole tree manually", as in "chmod -R" you mean?  It isn't the public that needs access, just Apache.  Probably www-data.  I do hope www-data owns /var/www/html and is the Apache user?  Both chown and chmod know the "-R" option.  But if there are no files in /var/www/html, this is moot.

Comment: Thanks for your patience.
index.html returns Forbidden and this is, naturally, because permissions were 600. The files are accessible to the web now, but new files need to be manually changed.
www-data is indeed the apache user, but `ls -i` doesn't name an owner. This, despite me using `chown -R`
This doesn't seem to be my issue. What's causing each individual file to be created with 600 permissions?

Comment: Owner of directories also howard:www-data.
How do I figure out why each new file defaults to 600?

Comment: By studying the intricacies of vsftpd. and the client used to upload those files.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with RHEL 8.x instead of Ubuntu, after checking all the permissions, the issue was SELINUX was enabled in the system.

Solved by editing /etc/selinux/config and changing the line:

```
SELINUX=enforcing
by
SELINUX=disabled
```

Then reboot.